# SQL to add column and comment in table in single command

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g for my web application. I want to add a column and a comment to an existing table. I can do that easily with the below commands

```
ALTER TABLE product ADD product_description VARCHAR2(20)
```

and

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN product.product_description 
     IS 'This is comment for the column';
```

But I want to do above task in single command. I searched on internet for a command to add a column and comment in a single command but I couldn't find. I wonder if this is possible. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: it is the only way to do on Oracle

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, you can't.

There's no reason why you would need to. This is a one-time operation and so takes only an additional second or two to actually type and execute.

If you're adding columns in your web application this is more indicative of a flaw in your data-model as you shouldn't need to be doing it.

---

In response to your comment that a comment is a column attribute; it may *seem* so but behind the scenes Oracle stores this as an attribute of an *object*.

```
SQL> desc sys.com$
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 OBJ#                                      NOT NULL NUMBER
 COL#                                               NUMBER
 COMMENT$                                           VARCHAR2(4000)

SQL>
```

The column is optional and `sys.col$` does not contain comment information.

I assume, I have no knowledge, that this was done in order to only have one system of dealing with comments rather than multiple.

Comment: Thanks @Ben for your answer. You are right, it is one time operation and takes additional second to execute. But still I was looking for any syntax to club them in one. Because I think comment is like any other attribute of column. I was wondering if you can add column with datatype(must), contraints(optional) then why not comment?

Comment: @SunilChavan, I've updated my answer slightly. Yes, it does seem like that should be the case but it's not, technically the case.

Comment: Whack it all in a script @Sven? Not sure how it's different to deploying any other code - it's a load easier than altering DDL as its a "replace" and so you can overwrite what was there previously.

Comment: Adding columns to a web application is often indicative of a new feature. Lack of a column to support a new feature is not a flaw in the data model.

Comment: I wrote _in_ your application, not _for_ your application. There's a very big difference.

Comment: Second and third paragraph should be deleted.

Answer (score 32):

You can use below query to update or create comment on already created table.

SYNTAX:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN TableName.ColumnName IS 'comment text';
```

Example:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN TAB_SAMBANGI.MY_COLUMN IS 'This is a comment on my column...';
```

Comment: is this Oracle-DB only? Or Standard SQL?

Comment: More information [COMMENT ON COLUMN](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COMMENT/COMMENTONCOLUMN.htm)

Comment: I used in SQL server but it's not worked :(

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? The OP already knew the syntax for `comment on column`.

Answer (score 6):

Query to add column with comment are :

```
alter table table_name 
add( "NISFLAG"    NUMBER(1,0) )

comment on column "ELIXIR"."PRD_INFO_1"."NISPRODGSTAPPL" is 'comment here'

commit;
```

Answer (score -1):

Table Comments -RightClick on Table Name GoTo Properties Add to Extended Properties MS_Description as property name and add comments.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Add comments for two different columns of the EMPLOYEE table :

```
COMMENT ON EMPLOYEE
     (WORKDEPT IS 'see DEPARTMENT table for names',
     EDLEVEL IS 'highest grade level passed in school' )
```